# VHDL Frequency Meter that reads NCO

Tags: vhdl, frequency, fpga, quartus, nco

<hi guys im trying to make an auto-ranging 4-digit frequency meter for measuring signals with frequencies from
10 Hz to 10 MHz. An external 1 MHz generator is used to provide a clock signal to the meter. To do this I have made an NCO to generate frequency but I dont know how to make the frequency meter. Any clues or examples you can show me? From what I understand is you can use "1 sec gate" to compare your rising_edge from NCO pulses to another clock, maybe Im wrong Help Please.

NCO code

```
    
ENTITY PA IS
    -- N:width of address 2^N; M:width of accumultor;
    GENERIC(N:natural:=12;
                M:natural:=26);
    PORT(
        clk: IN STD_LOGIC; -- 50 MHz
        nrst: IN STD_LOGIC;
        -- 100Hz resolution, Fres=Fclk/(2^M)
        phase_inc: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(M-1 DOWNTO 0);
        address: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
    );
END PA;

ARCHITECTURE PA_IMPL OF PA IS
    SIGNAL accum: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(M-1 DOWNTO 0):=(OTHERS=>'0');
BEGIN
    PROCESS(clk,nrst)
    BEGIN
        IF(nrst='0') THEN
            accum <= (OTHERS=>'0');
        ELSIF(rising_edge(clk)) THEN
                if (accum >= "10111110101111000010000000") then --capping it at 50MHZ
            accum <=phase_inc;
                else
                accum <= phase_inc + accum ; --accum into phase freq in?
                end if;
        END IF;    
    END PROCESS;    
    address <= accum(M-1 DOWNTO M-N);
     --msb_o <= count(count'left);
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

Comment: *Any clues or examples you can show me?* is [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). See [ask].

Comment: Don't do arithmetic on std_logic_vectors, or compare with "1011_....". Use signed or unsigned as appropriate from numeric_std and compare with integers to make life easier(up to 31 or 32 bits:  above that, hex is easier). And no, if your input is a digital signal, or you can detect zero crossings on a sampled analog one, you don't need to worry about synthesisable FFTs.

Answer (score 0):

Doing an actual frequency meter is not that easy.

The simpliest way I see is to perform a Fast fourier transform on your sampled signal (you have IPs and VHDL code on internet for this), then find the peaks of the FFT to obtains the frequency. To do this you can just search on your entire FFT to find the highest value.

Also, be sure to have a sampling frequency of at least twice the maximum frequency your detector can measure.